# Navbar Delayed Affix to Top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

For some reason the navbar affixes itself to the top only after the page is almost entirely done loading. This creates an unusual pause in which the navbar floats a bit lower than the top of the page without its added formatting attributes.

I'd post the source, but I'm really unsure as to what may be the cause of this error and I can't point to a specific line of code. I'm using the standard Bootstrap boilerplate, though, and the rest of my site's source code can be found through the standard "View Page Source" method (my edited CSS is under "css/main.css").

http://www.radioairlift.org

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately you do not need to use the Bootstrap Affix plug-in to do what you are wanting! In Bootstrap 2.3.2 there is the class **.navbar-fixed-top**. To quote [their docs:](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar)

> Add .navbar-fixed-top and remember to account for the hidden area underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the . Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS.

So all you will want to do is remove the **.affix** class from **#nav** and remove the **position: relative** that you are adding in your CSS file to the nav id.

Answer (score 0):

There's a delay as the bootstrap javascript is loaded and processed.  Bootstrap is adding the "affix" class to your nav, which changes the position from "relative" to "fixed" (along with some other properties).

You may be able to add the "affix" class to the #nav in the HTML source and avoid the change in the styling.